# Can't compile Objective-C code with clang

Tags: objective-c, clang

I get following error with following Objective-C code, while trying to compile it with clang.

Obj-C Code:

```
// first program example

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
       NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
main.m:6:5: error: unexpected '@' in program
    @autoreleasepool {
    ^
main.m:7:38: error: extraneous ')' before ';'
    NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
                                 ^
main.m:7:16: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.m:9:5: error: expected identifier or '('
    return 0;
    ^
main.m:10:1: error: expected external declaration
}
^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```

I can compile without error within XCode.

Clang info:
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: What version of clang are you using? `@autoreleasepool{}` is new-ish, and Clang is moving fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need clang v3.0 or greater to use `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: Alright, good to know. I just wanted to update clang via MacPorts, then it told me that version 2.9 is out, so I installed clang 2.9, which is still installing. I guess I'll have to remove that version and will install 3.x after.

Comment: Ok, for some reason I can't install the latest version of clang on my system. Installing it works, but it will still use the old version. I just installed the latest XCode today, according to the second answer in this post, I should have clang 3.0 already installed on my system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674546/how-to-update-llvm-clang-on-mac-osx

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The command line tools are not included in the newest XCode version anymore (4.3.1). Therefore you need to download and install manually from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Comment: @cherrun: You can install them from the Xcode preferences window, too.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you have clang 3.0 on your system path you can compile your code with:

```
clang -Wall -framework Foundation prog_name.m -o prog_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to upgrade your Clang; the `@autoreleasepool{}` directive was released at the same time as ARC, and requires v3.0 or greater.