# How can I update clang to 3.3 on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, llvm, clang

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 and want to install TextMate 2, which is for Mac OS X 10.7+.
But all what it needs is a newer version of clang (LLVM), which is included in Lion and Mountain Lion. I read before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674546/how-to-update-llvm-clang-on-mac-osx) I can do that with MacPorts. So I used `port install clang` and MacPorts updated to clang-2.9, then clang-3.2 and finally clang-3.3. I thought, its updated now and I checked the version: `clang --version`. And it's not updated:

```
 Apple clang version 2.0 (tags/Apple/clang-139) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
 Thread model: posix
```

`So I copied the new clang file in this path (`/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/bin`) to`/usr/bin`. But now there's a fail :( :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libLLVM-3.3svn.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/bin/clang   
Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap
```

The `libLLVM-3.3svn.dylib` is at `/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/lib`. What can I do now, that
it runs clang-3.3? Sorry for my not perfect english ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `clang` from `/usr/bin`, it will be looking for the LLVM library in `/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-3.3svn.dylib`, i.e., `/usr/lib/libLLVM-3.3svn.dylib` (at least that's what the dynamic loader is telling you). You could try to copy the lib file into `/usr/lib`.

Alternatively, you can just download a more recent official build of Clang here:
http://llvm.org/releases/download.html

As far as I know, these builds are self-contained and do not need any dynamic libraries. However, it could be necessary to copy Apple's ARC libraries into a certain directory. If you run into trouble, please ask again.

Another approach is to build Clang and LLVM from source. You can find the repository URLs and instructions here:
http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

This should also build Clang with the LLVM libraries statically linked.

3.3, by the way, has not been officially released, so I would recommend using 3.2 unless you need any specific new features.