# How can I use the pre-compiled binaries to update to clang 3.3 on Mac OS 10.6.x?

Tags: macos, clang, llvm-clang, precompiled, binaries

I'm trying to install/update my clang from Apple clang version 1.7 (tags/Apple/clang-77) (based on LLVM 2.9svn) to clang version 3.3. I've downloaded the pre-compiled binaries into usr/bin/, as suggested by other posts ([How can I update clang to 3.3 on Mac OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701224/how-can-i-update-clang-to-3-3-on-mac-os-x-10-6)).

The point of this installation/update is to be able to use C++ code (not written by me, and written for a newer machine OS 10.8.x) on my mac. I would preferentially use Xcode to update this, but unfortunately, Apple has not made the necessary version of Xcode available for free without a developer's subscription.

I've edited my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include clang3.3/bin/ and clang3.3/lib, but I get an "Illegal Instruction" error and it's not clear to me why this is.

What I'd really like is to try the whole process again from the beginning with a step-by-step outline of the process, like is seen here ([How to install clang pre-built binaries ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657261/how-to-install-clang-pre-built-binaries-ubuntu-12-04?lq=1)), except for Mac OSX system, not Ubuntu.

I realize there are some previous threads that ask almost the same question, but I am asking specifically for these versions (and from a standpoint that includes very little experience installing via terminal/understanding pathways/etc.).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Xcode is free these days, as is the latest version of OS X (10.9) - why not just upgrade and save yourself a lot of hassle?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would actually create more hassle for version control for other (arguably more important to me) things on my computer, so it's not a trivial solution. That's the eventual solution when it's time to get a new computer, but until then, I am trying to fix the problem as described above.
As I mentioned, Apple has not actually made the version of Xcode I need for 10.6 freely available, otherwise that would be my go-to solution.