# A dilemma in developing LLVM project on Mac OS X : the most recent LLVM source vs. old LLVM binary on Mac

Tags: macos, llvm

My OS is Mac OS X 10.9. I am trying to develop an LLVM project which requires setting the LLVM source path to some environment variable, say LLVM_SRC_PATH.

However, it seems that there is no llvm source on Mac. So I have downloaded the recent llvm source (v 3.6) via its [git mirror](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm).

The dilemma is, my OS X uses llvm 3.5 (from `clang --version'), which implies a possible inconsistency between my source of LLVM and the binary of LLVM that the OS uses by default.  Naturally, I would update my machine's LLVM binary by compiling the newly downloaded LLVM source.  But then I see the [stackoverflow answer to someoneelse's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674546/how-to-update-llvm-clang-on-mac-osx), which basically says it is a bad idea to update llvm on Mac.

Perhaps I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use macports it will install LLVM in the /opt directory with and easy way to deactivate it. This was you won't overwrite the system compiler accidentally.

Comment: Just for people coming here today. Homebrew will let you do the same. You can install your own copy of clang or llvm, as long as you put them in a different directory, and use that for your development.